# How come GraphicsDevice.Viewport is in the wrong place?

Tags: c#, winforms, mouse, mousemove, xna-4.0

I derive `GraphicsControl` from `Control`:

```
public abstract class GraphicsControl : Control
{
    GraphicsDeviceService graphicsDeviceService;  

    protected override void OnCreateControl ( )
    {
        // Don't initialize the graphics device if we are running in the designer.
        if (!DesignMode)
        {
            graphicsDeviceService =
                GraphicsDeviceService.AddReference
                (
                Handle,
                new System.Drawing.Size ( ClientSize.Width,
                    ClientSize.Height )
                );

            // Register the service, so components like ContentManager can find it.
            services.AddService ( graphicsDeviceService );

            // Give derived classes a chance to initialize themselves.
            Initialize ( );
        }

        base.OnCreateControl ( );
    }

    string DeviceBeginDraw ( )
    {
        //    ensure drawing is valid

        //    set up viewport
        Viewport viewport = new Viewport 
            ( 
                ClientRectangle.X,
                ClientRectangle.Y, 
                ClientSize.Width, 
                ClientSize.Height 
            );

        viewport.MinDepth = 0;
        viewport.MaxDepth = 1;

        GraphicsDevice.Viewport = viewport;


        if (viewport.Bounds.Contains ( mouse.X, mouse.Y ))
        {
            //  fire event
            OnMouseMoved(this, 
                new MouseMovedEventArgs(new Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Point(mouse.X, mouse.Y)));
        }
    }
}
```

Then the derived `Canvas` *control* as follows:

```
public sealed class Canvas : GraphicsControl
{
    //    subscribe to MousedMoved event
}
```

The area responding to the mouse movement is located at the screens upper left (0, 0). The overall area overlaps the intended base control but is not Docked, filling the Parent control. See Image:

[image: Viewport does not fill the intended parent control area.]

Can anyone tell me what I might be doing wrong? If additional code is required, just ask.

Also, [MSDN seems to reference `ClientRectangle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203889%28v=xnagamestudio.31%29.aspx) as the property to use.

Comment: You are aware that ClientRectangle always is at (0,0) as it is in client coordinates? You probably need to explicitly convert from Client To Screen coordinates. Maybe you need to P/invoke ClientToScreen.....

Comment: Does this need to be moved to Game Development? I guess I'll have to start another bounty.

Comment: When I get the Tumbleweed badge for this one, I sure wish it would make cricket sounds when I click on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I found the problem here:

```
graphicsDeviceService =
    GraphicsDeviceService.AddReference
    (
    Handle,
    new System.Drawing.Size ( ClientSize.Width,
        ClientSize.Height )
    );
```

Since GraphicControl derives from `Control`, `base.Handle` is passing in the handle of the base control class rather than the handle of the owning `System.Windows.Forms.Form`. Once the owning Form's Handle is passed to graphicsDeviceService, the mouse tracks perfectly.

```
public abstract class GraphicsControl : Control
{
    protected GraphicsControl ( System.Windows.Forms.Form Owner )
    {
        owner = Owner;
    }

    protected override void OnCreateControl ( )
    {
            // construction logic
            graphicsDeviceService =
                GraphicsDeviceService.AddReference
                (
                    owner.Handle,
                    vpRectangle
                );

            // more construction logic

            // Give derived classes a chance to initialize themselves.
            Initialize ( );
        }

        base.OnCreateControl ( );
    }

}
```